# Excel to Image without api in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am having a linux machine and want `system drawing` to convert a excel table to image for Free.

Here is my code

```
using GrapeCity.Documents.Excel;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Create a new workbook
        var workbook = new GrapeCity.Documents.Excel.Workbook();
        Console.WriteLine("Working...");
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Test121.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
        
        //Open a xlsx file 
        workbook.Open(fileStream);
        IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        
        //Export the worksheet to image 
        worksheet.ToImage("Test121.png");
        Console.WriteLine("Done!!");
    }
}
```

but this gives a warning at top of image that it is unlicensed

I also could not use Spire.XLS as my excel file could have more than 200 rows.

btw i am using C#.Net on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: saving as image's result can vary from libraries, and maybe microsoft interop is best for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1288110/1518100

Comment: will it work in linux

Comment: i'm afraid not. after reading your question again, i noticed you want to save specific 2d table to image, instead of arbitrary excel range. so you can search for 'C# reporting' tools,  for example https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport

Comment: @LeiYang i wanted to convert my excel sheet content to image but in this code i have to purchase GC excel. But i wanted a free conversion ie. from system.

Comment: the library FastReport is open source, let alone free.

Comment: i don't want to depend my app on any api. it should be independent and could run on any platform

Comment: how do you define an **api**? can you give an example that is very useful but is not an api?

Comment: **api** like `GrapeCity.Documents.Excel` is an external api added to my project

Comment: `GrapeCity.Documents.Excel` is what you don't want. please give an example that is both useful and you don't need add to your project.

Comment: Do you want to draw a range exactly as it would appear in excel? Then you'll have to use excel (probably). Otherwise you can use the openxml package to read a spreadsheet file, locate the values in a range, then do whatever you want with that data. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes i want to draw a range, but with **openxml** how to convert it to image

Comment: @JeremyLakeman can you answer please

Comment: How to take data from openxml and render an image. That is out of scope for an SO answer. Just because excel makes it look easy, doesn't mean there is any easy way without using excel. Unless there's a library which already exists, but which you don't want to pay for. But you already ruled that out.